# insert column into array using scaler obj (numpy.insert)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, data-manipulation

```
    import numpy as np
    a = np.array([[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]])
    print(a,'\n')
    c2 = np.insert(a, [1], [[9],[99],[999]], axis=1)
    print(c2,'\n')
    c3 = np.insert(a, 1, [9,99,999], axis=1)
    print(c3,'\n')
    c4 = np.insert(a, 1, [[9],[99],[999]], axis=1)
    print(c4,'\n')
    c5 = np.insert(a, [1], [9,99,999], axis=1)
```

```
>>>the result:
[[1 6]
 [2 7]
 [3 8]]

c2 = 
[[  1   9   6]
 [  2  99   7]
 [  3 999   8]]

c3 = 
[[  1   9   6]
 [  2  99   7]
 [  3 999   8]] 

c4 = 
[[  1   9  99 999   6]
 [  2   9  99 999   7]
 [  3   9  99 999   8]]

c5 = 
[[  1   9  99 999   6]
 [  2   9  99 999   7]
 [  3   9  99 999   8]]
```

why C4 did not take column value and insert it before each item in column 1
i think it should be
[[  1   9   6][  2  99   7][  3 999   8]]

also

```
a = np.array([[1, 6], [5, 2]])
print(a,'\n')

c4 = np.insert(a, 1, [[9,88],[99,66]], axis=1)
print(c4,'\n')
```

why the result is equal to

```
[[ 1  9 99  6]
 [ 5 88 66  2]]
```

not equal to

```
[[ 1  9 88  6]
 [ 5 99 66  2]]
```

while the insert axis along axis 0 will inserted normally

```
c11 = np.insert(a, 1, [9,99], axis=0)
print(c11,'\n')
c12 = np.insert(a, 1, [[9],[99]], axis=0)
print(c12,'\n')
```

the result:

```
[[ 1  6]
 [ 9 99]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]] 

[[ 1  6]
 [ 9  9]
 [99 99]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]]
```

Comment: `insert` docs say there's a difference between using `1` and `[1]`, but isn't overly clear.  It appears than with the scalar location is transposes the values.  The code is complex, so it's hard to trace exactly what's happening.  With some inputs I get `broadcasting` error, implying that it creates a target with `n` open slots, and using broadcasting to assign the values to them.  How many slots appears to depend on the index size and values shape.

Comment: If `np.insert` is too confusing, do your own 'insert'.  Use `concatenate` if inserting at the end or beginning.  Or create a recipient array of the right shape, and assign values - from the original array and new.  `insert` is just a convenience tool, it doesn't add any essential functionality.

Comment: no , the scaler object did not transpose the the value, because the insert method for axis 0 will be inserted normally. please see the the question after edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching we found the answer as below:

the output of scaler index was 1d array

```
a = np.array([[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]])
print(a)
print(a[:,1])
print(a[:,[1]])
    
>>> 
a
[[1 6]
 [2 7]
 [3 8]]

a[:,1]
 [6 7 8]

a[:,[1]]
 [[6]
 [7]
 [8]]
```

so when using scaler index to insert column along axis 1, the values will be assigned for scaler output (1d array) , then transpose the scaler output values to fit the indexed column.

```
a = np.array([[1, 6], [5, 2]])
print(a,'\n')

c4 = np.insert(a, 1, [[9,88],[99,66]], axis=1)
print(c4,'\n')
```

a[:,1]

```
a[:,1] = [a01 a11] = [[9  88]
                     [99 66]]
```

so the

```
a01 = [[9 ]      a11 = [[88]
       [99]]            [66]]
```

after that a[:,1] will be transposed to fit with column

```
[[ 1  9 99  6]
 [ 5 88 66  2]]
```

while when using scaler index to insert column along axis 1, the scaler output will fit row index,

```
a = np.array([[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]])
c11 = np.insert(a, 1, [9,99], axis=0)
print(c11,'\n')
c12 = np.insert(a, 1, [[9],[99]], axis=0)
print(c12,'\n')
```

a[1,:] of c11

```
a[1,:] = [a10 a11] = [9  99]
```

so the

```
a10 = [9]      a11 = [99]
```

a[1,:] of c12 (the values will be broadcasting) to fit obj

```
a[1,:] = [a10 a11] = [[9  9 ]                         
                      [99 99]]
```

so the

```
a10 = [[9 ]      a11 = [[9 ]
       [99]]            [99]]
```

the result:

```
[[ 1  6]
 [ 9 99]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]] 

[[ 1  6]
 [ 9  9]
 [99 99]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]]
```